# Prop types in Vue wrapper component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

There is properly typed `BaseComp` base component, which can be a third-party component and so can't be rewritten to suit our needs:

```
<script lang="ts">
...
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'BaseComp',

  props: {
    baseProp: {
      type: String,
    },
    anotherBaseProp: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  ...
});
</script>
```

And `MyComp` wrapper component:

```
<template>
  <BaseComp
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :base-prop="myBaseProp"
    :another-base-prop="someProp"
  />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
...
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyComp',

  components: { BaseComp },

  props: {
    baseProp: {
      type: String,
    },
    someProp: {
      type: String,
    },
  },

  setup(props) {
    const myBaseProp = computed(() => transform(props.baseProp));

    return { myBaseProp };
  },
});
</script>
```

`MyComp` is expected to have the same prop types as `BaseComp` in TypeScript, plus `someProp` - both internally (`props` inside `setup` function) and externally (templates and render functions).

The use of `$attrs` works as it should at runtime but `MyComp` won't get unlisted prop types from `BaseComp` at compilation time (`anotherBaseProp`).

`MyComp` doesn't use `extends` as it doesn't inherit all component options, just props.

What is the proper way to make `MyComp` expose the correct props?

Can it allow to not list common props a wrapper that it explicitly uses (`someProp`)?

Answer (score 1):

In Vue3, you have two ways to do this: with [`mixins`](https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#mixins) or [`composition api`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits). The composition api being the recommended way to do as stated in the Vue 3 documentation.

Officially, you can't extends only some parts of another components without extending it entirely.

### Inherit from a external component (no access to source code)

EDIT: There is a solution that is not documentation and may be breakpoint for various reasons.

If possible, I do not recommend to use this method unless it has been officially documented somehow.

```
import BaseComp from 'BaseComp.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyComp',
  components: { BaseComp },
  props: {
    ...BaseComp.props, // Object containing BaseComp props object
  },
});
```

---

### EDIT: You have access to the parent component's code

#### With composition api

Export a function with the common props definition.

```js
export const useGlobalProps = () => {
  return {
    baseProp: {
      type: String,
    },
    someProp: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
}
```

##### with `defineComponent` method

```js
import { useGlobalProps } from 'globalProps'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'BaseComp',
  props: {
    ...useGlobalProps(),
    otherProp: Boolean,
  }
  ...
});
```

##### or `script setup` model

```
<script setup>
import { useGlobalProps } from 'globalProps'

defineProps({
  ...useGlobalProps(),
  otherProps: Boolean,
})
</script>
```

#### With mixins

```js
// base-mixin.js
export default {
  props: {
    baseProp: {
      type: String,
    },
    someProp: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
}
```

```
import BaseMixin from 'base-mixin'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'BaseComp',
  mixins: [BaseMixin],
  ...
});

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyComp',
  mixins: [BaseMixin],
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it can be useful. In my specific case BaseComp is third-party component that I won't refactor, so this approach isn't suitable in general.

Comment: You should have specified this in your question haha. Indeed this doesn't apply if you don't have access to the component's code.
This is not documented and may not work for various reasons, but you can actually use `BaseComp.props` after importing it. I edited my answer.

Comment: "BaseComp.props" - was this tested? I've got mixed results with it, BaseComp seemed to be `any`, and I'm not sure if it was because of problems in my environment

Comment: I tested it with a Vue 3 app, it appears to work with a simple component using script setup. But as said, this is not an official behaviour, it may break depending on how the component code is written. Also, if it's not written with Typescript, you'll obviously have no types for this.